# How to use REPL to test Strongloop-Loopback query

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

How can I use REPL to test a strongloop query. Currently I'm using routes.js to test the queries, which doesn't seem good.

```
router.get('/sample', function (req, res) {
    var Brand = app.models.Brand;
    Brand.find({
        skip: 2,
        limit: 3
    }, function (err, data) {
        res.send(data);
    })
});
```

Then I run the application using slc run command and then type in url

```
http://localhost:3001/sample
```

which will give me the result of the query. Is there a better way? Thanks!

Comment: i mean... you could boot the app, grab your model from it,and execute methods on it. right? `>a = require('./app');` `>a.models.Brand.find(...)`

Comment: @Kevin B 22 I've tried that but in vain
> var loopback = require('loopback');
undefined
> var app = module.exports = loopback();
undefined
> var x = app.models.Brand;
undefined
> x
undefined
>

Comment: I'm not familiar with current versions of loopback so i may have missed a step. but it should definitely be possible, assuming you're exporting the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no REPL for LoopBack queries. However, you can test your queries using `loopback-explorer. See https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Use+API+Explorer.